# solution set of $2x+y\ge{8},x+2y\ge 10,x\ge0,y\ge0$

Tags: inequality

> How do I prove that the solution set of the inequalities $2x+y\ge{8},x+2y\ge 10,x\ge0,y\ge0$ is an unbounded region ?

I can see that the statement is true graphically by plotting each inequalities. But what does it mean mathematically ?

How do I prove it without actually plotting it ?

Comment: Is not $(x,x)$ a point of the region for any $x\ge 4?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unbounded because if you solve the system of inequalities which means that ALL of them must be satisfied you get the region $\mathcal{R}$ of the plane where

$(y\geq 8-2x) \land (y\geq 5-\dfrac{x}{2})\land (x\geq 0 )\land (y\geq 0)$

As you can see all the results contain $\geq$  which means that, even if we want to be cautious, we can take the largest values for $x$ and for $y$ which satisfy ALL the previous inequalities for instance $\mathcal{S}=(x\geq 10;\;y\geq 10)$  and we have a subregion of the plane $\mathcal{S}\subset \mathcal{R}$ which is unbounded, so to a greater extent is unbounded $\mathcal{R}$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

If you show there is no value for max/min then you prove that it is unbounded. [Feasible region](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feasible_region#Bounded_and_unbounded_feasible_sets)

Answer (score 0):

Let $(x_n, y_n)=(10n, 10n)$; 
it is easy to chech out 
this point satisfies all the above inequalities.

Also notice that 
$ 
\underset{n \rightarrow }{\lim}x_n= 
\underset{n \rightarrow }{\lim}x_n= 
\infty $; so this region can not be bounded; 
so this region must be unbounded!

---

---

**Remark(I)**: 
For every point $(z,w)$ and for every real number $0 < M$; 
there exists $n$ such that:

$$\sqrt{(x_n-z)^2+(y_n-w)^2}=|| (x_n,y)-(z_n,w) || > M$$

---

**Proof of boundedness.**

**Suppose  on contrary** that: 
this region is bounded;

so there exist a point $(z,w)$ and a radios $0 < M$ 
such that for every point (x,y) of the region 
we have:

$$\sqrt{(x-z)^2+(y-w)^2}=|| (x,y)-(z,w) || \leq M.$$

But notice that for every $n \in \mathbb{N} $, 
$(x_n,y_n)$ belongs to this region; 
which has an obvious contradiction with **Remark(I)**

---

---

---

---

**Remark(II)**: 
Note that in a euclidian's plane 
if a region  is bounded 
then the sequence of 
the $x$-coordintate of 
every sequence must have a accumulation point.

Comment: thnx. i'm srry could you please explain why you taking why you taking $(x_n,y_n)=(10n,10n)$. Is there any general way of showing the region is unbounded by using the algebra of inequalities ?

Comment: @ss1729 , I have explained more. Does it satisfies you?